# enhancing a select sqlite query for performance

Tags: sqlite, query-performance

I have a return dataset of around 11k records on this sqlite query. Is there a scope for changes in this query that can help performance gain. Thanks

```
SELECT count(*) as count, easting,northing FROM tableName where site='K' AND is_deleted=0 AND easting !='' AND northing !='' AND easting !=0 AND northing !=0.
```

here' s the table structure from where i will pull the records:

```
CREATE TABLE "g_livcol" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,
"accession_no" INTEGER NOT NULL ,
"isLive" VARCHAR(5),
"taxanomic_name" VARCHAR(50),
"genus_name" VARCHAR(50),
"taxanomic_species" VARCHAR(50),
taxanomic_species2 VARCHAR(50),
taxon_is_epithet VARCHAR(50),
taxanomic_cv VARCHAR(50),
sec_key INTEGER,
site VARCHAR(5),
location_key VARCHAR(20),
sub_location1 INTEGER, 
sub_location2 INTEGER,
count_of_loc_key INTEGER,
accession_quantity INTEGER,
canopy INTEGER,
height INTEGER,
easting DOUBLE,
northing DOUBLE, 
created_at DATETIME,
updated_at DATETIME, 
is_deleted BOOL DEFAULT (0))
```

Comment: How are you comparing easting both to number and string?

Comment: Show the table structure, any indexes you have, and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: @CL. right this is a mistake its always gonna be a decimal. Here' s the table structure anyway

Comment: You added the table structure, but not the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an index created for it? I suppose the most discriminating column is `site`, so you need an index starting with that.

Further, do you have a [covering index](https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#covidx) for it? You are only reading three columns and testing one more from rather wide table, so covering index can help here:

```
create index tableName_i1 on tableName (site, is_deleted, easting, northing, id);
```

The index is "covering", because it contains everything the query needs.

Actually, due to the "*" in the count the optimizer may not realize that, so I suggest using `count(id)` instead of `count(*)`. It is the same, because `id` is primary key, but it makes it more obvious to the optimizer it does not need to read anything else.